# how to append same header data to one header in linux

Tags: linux, shell

my data is seperated by comma delimiter
So by talking value before comma as main header column and if the same header occured somewhere elese, apped data into one header by placing open and closed flower brackets

Please consider my example for better understading

Input file data

```
19,66:BILL
19,34
19,02
21,:0
21,:0
21,:1
21,37
26,:19
26,87
27,35
31,77
31,12
31,202
```

Output file data

```
19,{66:BILL}{34}{02}
21,:{0}{:0}{:1}
21,37
26,{:19}{87}
27,35
31,{77}{12}{102}
```

Comment: "*Flower brackets?*" (aren't those called *braces*?) What have you tried so far? `awk` will work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]"{"$2"}"} END{for (i in a) print i FS a[i]}' input.csv
```

Assuming that the input file contains two columns only, the script constructs an array `a` by appending the values `$2` of all rows with the same index `$1` into the same element `a[$1]`

**input.csv**

```
19,66:BILL
19,34
19,02
21,:0
21,:0
21,:1
21,37
26,:19
26,87
27,35
31,77
31,12
31,202
```

**output**

```
19,{66:BILL}{34}{02}
21,{:0}{:0}{:1}{37}
26,{:19}{87}
27,{35}
31,{77}{12}{202}
```